# yii: changed date format in widget but still getting stored as 000-00-00

Tags: php, yii

I changed the following `yy-mm-dd` to `dd-mm-yy` and the database shows the date field is set to `0000-00-00`.

_form.php

```
$form->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'datestart',
            'value' => $model->datestart,
            'options' => array(
                'showButtonPanel' => true,
                'changeYear' => true,
                'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yy',
                ),
            ));
```

When I catch the `$_PARAM` being sent to the controller `save()` action, it shows that the date is being sent as `01-01-2014`.

However it's getting stored as `0000-00-00`. Where should I be looking? It seems like it's set to expect `yyyy-mm-dd` format somewhere. I generated the models via giix btw.

Comment: why dont you look at the format of the column in your table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `DATE` mysql field type, you need to make sure `dateFormat` returns the correct format for your `DATE` field. In this case `altFormat` is the format which is shown to the user. Also, add the `name` property too like so:

```
<?php 
$form->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'datestart',
    'value'=>$model->datestart,
    'name'=>$model->datestart,
    'options'=>array(
                    ...
                    'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',  // save format
                    'altFormat'=>'dd-mm-yy',  // show format
                    ...
               ),
));
?>
```

Comment: this gives me the error `Property "CJuiDatePicker.mode" is not defined.`

Comment: Ah my answer was based on `CJuiDateTimePicker` instead of `CJuiDatePicker` - I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using mysql as Database and mysql date field accept date value only **YYYY-mm-dd** format. It will not accept other format. So if you pass the date in **YYYY-mm-dd** format then it will store correctly otherwise it will store 0000-00-00 as date.